# Updating dropdown list after date change in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

While writing my code i've stumbled upon this problem:

I have the following code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegistryDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" name="RegistryDate" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-nonescaped"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorId, "Doctor", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.DropDownDoctorsFor(model => model.DoctorId, new { @class = "col-sm-7 form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

With my DropDownDoctor helper looking like this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownDoctorsFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttrubutes, string name = "")
    {
        var htmlAttr = GenerateHtmlAttributes(htmlAttrubutes);

        var db = new MyContext();

        var doctors = db.Workers.OfType<Doctor>().ToList();

        var doctorsListItem = doctors.Select(doctor => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = doctor.FirstName + " " + doctor.LastName + " | " + WorkerHelper.GetNumberOfPatientsForDoctor(doctor.Id) ,
            Value = doctor.Id.ToString()
        });


        if (name == "")
            name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var value = expression.Compile()(helper.ViewData.Model).ToString();

        StringBuilder dropdown = new StringBuilder();
        dropdown.Append(String.Format(@"<select name='{0}' {1}>", name, htmlAttr));
        string selected = "";
        foreach (var item in doctorsListItem)
        {
            if (value == item.Value)
                selected = "selected='selected'";
            else selected = "";
            dropdown.Append(String.Format("<option value='{0}' {1} >{2}</option>", item.Value, selected, item.Text));
        }
        dropdown.Append(@"</select>");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString());
    }
```

What i would like to do is to update the select list, so that it shows the number of patients for doctor on selected date with the default value for today. I have completely no idea how to do it. I would be really appreciative for any help.

Comment: Have a partial view for dropdown list and pass model and current date by default to view. On date change make ajax to get updated model for selected date and refresh partial view with latest model.

Comment: Alternatively, have a `JSONResult` action method on your controller that accepts the date and returns the data, then repopulates you `select` options (if you need an example let me know).  And please, I implore you to abandon your custom HtmlHelper.  It mixes data access in a view component and represents everything that MVC is not (separation of concerns)

Comment: Could you provide me with the solution that doesn't use the custom mvc helper to do that ? I would be grateful.